# How to keep text and image in a single line inside a div?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am trying to put title and content in a div vertically parallel to image div,
My [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c12omacv/) . But when ever the text content length in increasing the image is coming in next line.

```css
.archive .woocommerce-product-page .grid {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.card--sub-category.card--product-sub-cat {
    /* display: table; */
    margin: 30px 10px 30px 10px;
    /* background: #ffffff; */
    /* width: 100%; */
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
}
.sub-category-content {
    /* height: 100%; */
    overflow: auto;
}
.sub_category_card__content {
    /* padding-left: 10px; */
    padding-left: 0;
    font-weight: normal;
    /* float: left; */
}
.sub-cat-description .category-desc {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-align: left;
    display: block;
    font-size: small;
    color: #919191;
}
.product_post__thumbnail {
    float: right;
}
.product_post__thumbnail img {
    height: 75px;
    width: 75px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
}
```

```html
<div class="card--sub-category card--product-sub-cat">
    <a href="http://localhost/ahlihukum2/product-category/business/contracts-and-agreements/" class="sub-cat-page-link">
                        <div class="sub-category-content">
            <div class="sub_category_card__content">
                                <div class="sub-cat-title">
                    <h2 class="sub-category-title">
                            Contracts and Agreements                    </h2>
                </div>
                                <div itemprop="description" class="sub-cat-description">
                    <p class="category-desc">Review or create business contracts, review of employment contracts, consulting agreements and NDAs Review or create business contracts, review of employment contracts, consulting agreements and NDAs Review or create business contracts, review of employment contracts, consulting agreements and NDAs Review or create business contracts, review of employment contracts, consulting agreements and NDAs</p>
                </div>
                            </div>
                        <div class="product_post__thumbnail">
                <img src="http://localhost/ahlihukum2/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/criminal-defense-150x135.png">
            </div>
                    </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

I want the text to take all the sapce when there is no image.

Comment: Are you able to change your HTML markup at all?

Comment: @zgood yes, to some extend I can change my html markup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally achieve it.

```
    <div class="card--sub-category card--product-sub-cat">
    <a href="http://localhost/ahlihukum2/product-category/business/contracts-and-agreements/" class="sub-cat-page-link">
                        <div class="sub-category-content">
                                    <div class="product_post__thumbnail">
                        <img src="http://localhost/ahlihukum2/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/criminal-defense-150x135.png">
                    </div>
                                                <div class="sub-cat-title">
                    <h2 class="sub-category-title">
                            Contracts and Agreements                    </h2>
                </div>
                                <div itemprop="description" class="sub-cat-description">
                    <p class="category-desc">Review or create business contracts, review of employment contracts, consulting agreements and NDAs Review or create business contracts, review of employment contracts, consulting agreements and NDAs Review or create business contracts, review of employment contracts, consulting agreements and NDAs Review or create business contracts, review of employment contracts, consulting agreements and NDAs</p>
                </div>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

and css-

```
   .card--sub-category.card--product-sub-cat {
    margin: 30px 10px 30px 10px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
}
.sub-category-content {
    overflow: auto;
    padding-left: 0;
    font-weight: normal;
}
.product_post__thumbnail {
    float: right;
}
.product_post__thumbnail img {
    height: 75px;
    width: 75px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
}
.sub-category-title {
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #484848;
    margin-bottom: 4px;
    padding: 0;
}
.sub-cat-description .category-desc {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-align: left;
    display: block;
    font-size: small;
    color: #919191;
}
```

[jsfiddle of my working version](https://jsfiddle.net/f6oL105z/1/)

Answer (score 1):

U can try add 'width' and 'float: left' on < p > tag, something like this:

```html
.sub-cat-description .category-desc {

    float: left;
    width: 200px;

    margin-bottom: 0;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-align: left;
    display: block;
    font-size: small;
    color: #919191;


}
```

if u want to make it responsive, you should change your html structure and apply something like this:

```css
#img_container{
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  width: 150px;
  height: 135px;
  padding: 0px 0px 12px 12px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  
<p>
  <div id="img_container"><img src="http://localhost/ahlihukum2/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/criminal-defense-150x135.png"></div> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque vehicula erat augue, non mattis enim pretium non. Morbi sed purus a erat condimentum finibus et a diam. Quisque eleifend felis a pretium lobortis. Aenean eu porta libero. Donec nec ante in felis condimentum dapibus. Nam tincidunt mauris imperdiet posuere ullamcorper. Nam suscipit ex nulla, et ullamcorper ligula lacinia et. Nunc et nulla nunc. Sed vestibulum mi mauris, ut commodo urna porttitor id. Sed quis maximus elit.
</p>

</div>
```

Comment: if you will fix the width of category-desc how it will cover all the space when there will be no image ?

Comment: I don't know if the update helps you, but it works like u ask: if there is no img, the text fits on div.

Comment: have you seen my jsfiddle link ?

Comment: yeah! the first step u can do is put img div container insider your <p> tag, some css changes will be necessary.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out <p> tag , I think I have done it before, so let me try with <p> tag.

Comment: putting image div inside <p> tag results two empty paragraphs before and after of image div ?

Comment: And with your updated css, when there will be no image there will be empty space in place of image and the text will not occupy the empty spaces .

Answer (score 1):

I believe that using display: flex would be the best approach here.

Here is a great article on flex -> https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Find bellow your html code with 2 lines of css. :)

```css
.sub-category-content{
   display: flex;
   align-items: flex-start;
}
 
.sub_category_card__content{
    margin-right: 10px
}

.sub_category_card__content h2 {
    margin: 0;
}

.product_post__thumbnail > img {
    height:  75px;
    width: 75px;
}
```

```html
<div class="card--sub-category card--product-sub-cat">
  <a href="http://localhost/ahlihukum2/product-category/business/contracts-and-agreements/" class="sub-cat-page-link">
    <div class="sub-category-content">
      <div class="sub_category_card__content">
        <div class="sub-cat-title">
          <h2 class="sub-category-title">Contracts and Agreements</h2>
        </div>
        <div itemprop="description" class="sub-cat-description">
          <p class="category-desc">Review or create business contracts, review of employment contracts, consulting agreements and NDAs Review or create business contracts, review of employment contracts, consulting agreements and NDAs Review or create business contracts, review of employment contracts, consulting agreements and NDAs Review or create business contracts, review of employment contracts, consulting agreements and NDAs</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="product_post__thumbnail">
        <img src="http://perronelawpc.com/cscheader.png">
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Here I can not give height and width to image which I want 75px*75px .any solution to that ?

Comment: You can give the img a width and height. The wrapper div will grow accordingly tanks to flex. I'll update the .css making the image 75px*75px and will also give the sub_category_card__content a little margin right and so the image won't be touching the text.

Comment: If you want the image to align on the top instead of the center as per my code, change align-items: center to align-items: flex-start, or if you want to align it to the bottom, change align-items: center to align-items: flex-end.

Comment: I am up-voting it is as I feel it is helpful, but if you look into my solution the image starts in same line with title.

Comment: As per my comment above you could have changed the align-items property. I've changed the code to exemplify for you.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved generally by simply placing the image inside of the paragraph tags.

```
<p>Hello, this is some text.
<img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/5a/3f/28/5a3f2813a332b8aefdca5069a2ec7b50.jpg" width="100px" />
</p>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vnnf7yxz/

Comment: but how can I place <h2> inside <p> ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to get your divs to float left or right.

For example:

```
`<div style="width: 100%; border: 1px solid red;">
<div style="width: 100%; border: 1px solid red;"> link</div>
<div style="width: 100%; border: 1px solid red;"> 
Title
<div>
<p>
<div style=" width: 25%; border: 1px solid red; float: right;.">Pic </div>
<div style=" width: 50%; border: 1px solid red; float: Left;">Text </div>
</p>
</div></div>
</div>`
```

Comment: You can actually add this to your css. It is meant for demonstration and understanding.